# EF Core-Asp Net Core One toMany Relation Adding New Item

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi there I am trying to learn WebAPI's with asp net core and ef core.I have simple 2 entities named Post and Category. I created relation as I added.
Category:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryTitle { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Post:

```
 public class Post : BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AuthorName { get; set; }
    public string PostTitle { get; set; }
    public string PostContent { get; set; }
    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public EntryType Type { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
          
}
```

I thought a Category can have many posts about its field.
I used Fluent API in my Context class to create relation.

```
builder.Entity<Post>()
        .HasOne<Category>(s => s.Category)
        .WithMany(g => g.Posts)
        .HasForeignKey(s => s.CategoryId);
```

In my controllers, I am adding new post with categoryId When I request categories, I cannot see posts that attached current category. I attached response:

```
{
    "categoryId": 3,
    "name": "Computer",
    "title": "Technology",
    "posts": []
}
```

Should I see something on posts key? When I check categories with id, posts property is null.But I added new post with categoryId = 3.

Here is my request body:

```
{
  "author": "John Doe",
  "title": "AspNetCore",
  "content": "Backend",
  "categoryId": 3,
  "type": 2
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you do not include **Posts** while retrieving **Categories**. Try to include posts like this:

```
_context.Categories.Include(i=>i.Posts)
```

The **Include** method specifies the related objects to include in the query results. It can be used to retrieve some information from the database and also want to include related entities. Follow this link to learn about [**Lazy Loading**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy) and [**Eager Loading**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager).

Comment: Thanks for the help it works with Include. I will check the links.